# Set remember_me by default on symfony security authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I've got some issues with Symfony security, on the login method.

I create authentication by 3rd party system (I stored info about token from an external system associated with the user in my database), on success, I just select user data from database and authenticate by

```
return $guardHandler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess(
    $user,
    $request,
    $formAuthenticator,
    'main'
);
```

But, I want to set `remember_me` by default on this method of authorization.
I set in `security.yml`

```
main:
    anonymous: true
    lazy: true
    provider: app_user_provider
    switch_user: true
    remember_me:
        secret: '%kernel.secret%'
        lifetime: 2592000
        always_remember_me: true
```

But it works only with a normal login form, not when I use `authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess` method.

How can I set `remember_me` cookie by default in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code source it's documented :

```
/**
     * Does this method support remember me cookies?
     *
     * Remember me cookie will be set if *all* of the following are met:
     *  A) This method returns true
     *  B) The remember_me key under your firewall is configured
     *  C) The "remember me" functionality is activated. This is usually
     *      done by having a _remember_me checkbox in your form, but
     *      can be configured by the "always_remember_me" and "remember_me_parameter"
     *      parameters under the "remember_me" firewall key
     *  D) The onAuthenticationSuccess method returns a Response object
     *
     * @return bool
     */
public function supportsRememberMe();
```

Are all of thoses requirements met ?

Comment: Yes, it works with normal login form created with symfony-form component, but does not work with some custom code and manually call authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess